# flattering rxjs subscribers

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am new to Rxjs and trying to write some code

```
combineLatest( [poll$, user$ ]).subscribe( ([poll, user]) => {
       
        this.poll = poll;

        if( user.participated_in_polls.includes( poll._id )) {
          this.already_participated = true;
          return;
        }
       
        this.questionsService.get( poll._id ).subscribe( response => {
          this.questions = this.questionsQuery.getActive();

        });
      })
```

I have read that nested subscribe should be avoided. ButI have no clue how should I write this code to avoid nested `subscribe`  can someone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really want to get into using the pipe operator and higher order observable mapping operators such as mergeMap, switchMap, concatMap and so on. You then act on a stream of values rather than nested subscriptions.

Note this for the concept I am conveying only:

```
 combineLatest([poll$, user$])
  .pipe(
    tap((x) => this.poll = poll),
    filter((thing) => user.participated_in_polls.includes(poll._id)),
    mergeMap((otherThing) => {
      return this.questionsService.get(poll._id);
    })
  )
  .subscribe((streamEnd) => {

    this.questions = this.questionsQuery.getActive();
  });
```